# Acer ET322QK Monitor Glitches on 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

We recently upgraded our monitor to a 32 inch Acer ET322QK. The size is great, but we're having glitchy 'noise' pop up all over the place, especially when moving the mouse around, and also when watching things. I'm having a hard time narrowing down where it could be coming from. Running `lspci | grep HDMI` shows

`01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300/7300 Series]` which is the graphics card I have installed. Admittedly, I'm not great with graphics/drivers troubleshooting, is anyone out there? Any ideas? I attached a couple of screen shots if that helps. Thanks in advance.

[image: Screen glitch example 1]

[image: Screen glitch example 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found ubuntu drivers for my graphics card at https://www.amd.com/en/support and after installing them it made a big difference. Not 100% perfect, but 90% better. Hooray for those that make linux drivers.